# "Who you'll work with": change to View CV and hide link when no CV

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On a company page there is a section called "Who you'll work with".
When you hover over a person you have the option to **View Careers Profile**, can this be changed to **View CV**.

Also can the link be hidden if the person has not completed a CV?  Otherwise clicking on the View Careers Profile goes to a page not found.  Try it on the majority of SO employees:

[image]

As I keep trying this I am noticing some sort of strange bug that happens upon initial load.  Subsequent attempts seem to fix the issue but the initial bug still happens, here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Pick a company, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/102968/product-manager-stack-overflow?searchTerm=StackExchange&offset=0&ajax=1
2. Scroll to the section **Who you'll work with**
3. Hover over the view careers profile, note the url it is trying to go to shown at the bottom left of the image
   [image]
4. Click the link - result is page not found
5. Sometimes clicking back button fixes the issue, other times it doesn't.

Possible fix: instead of stackoverflow.com/... use careers.stackoverflow.com/...
Result for Marc Gravell: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/marcgravell?langCode=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent catch, Jon. Thanks for the report. All that should be fixed now.

Comment: This looks much better.  It's great that you guys are really taking the input on the jobs side and making it better.  I'm not getting paid by you guys but have pointed out a whole slew of things which make me feel that I have carved a piece of the jobs/careers functionality.  I wish I could do it full time it has been fun!

Comment: One nitpick, it still says Career Profile on the job listing (the company page one is fine)...

Comment: @JonH: Nitpick fixed (it'll go out in a few)

Comment: Thank you, this is much better!